# Missing values in google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am working with the practice repository in preparation for doing upcoming work with a large enterprise client using BQ. The repository link is: google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910

I have 3 questions to ask in relation to the sample repository & a query that was run (please see the bottom of the link for the query that motivated the question:

1) What is the difference between customDimensions.index, customDimensions.value and hits.customDimensions.index, hits.customDimensions.value?

2) If a single hit has multiple custom dimensions/metrics how is that returned/queried? I only see single dimensions matching at the hit level in the sample data.

3) There are no custom metric values passed in the example data, what will those values look like?

Here is the query that motivated the previous 3 questions:

```
SELECT hits.page.pagePath AS urls,
       hits.time,
       customDimensions.index,
       customDimensions.value,
       hits.customMetrics.index,
       hits.customMetrics.value,
       trafficSource.medium,
       hits.customVariables.index,
       hits.customVariables.customVarName,
       hits.customVariables.customVarValue
FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every record in that table represents one Google Analytics Session. Big Query has this concept of [nested fields](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested) and that's how individual hits are defined. They are nested into the hits record.

Answering your questions:

1) customDimensions.index and customDimensions.value are the index and value for user or session scoped custom dimensions. hits.customDimensions.index and hits.customDimensions.value re custom Dimensions set at hit scope level. The scope is defined when you create the custom Dimension through GA interface. indexes are integers from 1 to 20 (as defined in the Admin section) and value is the string passed as the value for that custom Dimension. [More info about Custom Dimensions/Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets)

2) Both rows and rows.customDimensions are REPEATED RECORDS in Big Query. So in essence every row in that BQ table looks like this:

```
|- date
|- (....)
+- hits
   |- time
   +- customDimensions
      |- index
      |- value
```

But when you query the data this should be FLATTEN by default. Because it's flatten if a single hit has multiple custom dimensions and metrics it should show multiple rows, one for each.

3) Should be the same as customDimensions but the values are INTEGER instead of STRINGS.

For a simpler and more educational dataset I suggest that you create a brand new BQ table and load the data provided on [this developer document page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested).

*PS: Tell my good friends at Cardinal Path that Eduardo said Hello!*

Comment: Thanks Eduardo! Great to also connect with you. I look forward to keeping in touch! Will send your hello's to the team at CP!